# Powering a water pump with nodemcu

Tags: esp8266, power, nodemcu

I want to use a nodemcu to water my plants. I connected a pump with a 2N2222 transistor (I know i should add a diode and a pull down on the gate). The pump is DSL370 and when it is off i measure 4.4V on the Vin pin while using a 2A charger connected to the USB port. When the pump is active, the vin voltage drops to 4.1V and the LCD becomes hard to read. I measured the current the pump uses and it is 300mA. What is the reason for the voltage drop? I thought the charger should be able to handle it.

[image: A schematic for my plant carrer]

Comment: Is this the pump you are using? https://www.aliexpress.com/item/YIXINYOU-DC-12V-Diaphragm-Vacuum-Pump-Water-Pump-Oxygen-Pump-Air-Pump-DSL-2-12-020/32819735122.html

Comment: Your question does not seem to have anything to do with either Arduino Hardware or Arduino software, so it is unclear on what basis it would belong on this site.  Generally for a motor you want an NFET, not a bipolar transistor, and you must not route the power *through* the microcontroller board.

Comment: It is indeed the pump i am using.

Answer (score 1):

Your charger may be able to handle 300mA, but you're pulling that power through your Arduino and that isn't good.  The pump should have a separate power supply, or at least be powered in parallel with the Arduino.  Don't pull power for a motor from the Vin pin unless you just want to destroy the Arduino.

Comment: But as shown here: http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/
The Vin is connected to the USB port via a diode so the power does not go "through" the Arduino.

Comment: @zbut you just described the power for the pump doing through the MCU board and specifically its diode, which exactly what you were told was a bad idea.